# MkCircle with MapKit, synchronyse with current user location

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am working in a project with MapKit, and I want to update the location of circle in the center of current user location. I can do that by implementing this methods. The problem is that user location when changes its coordinates animates and the method DidUpdateUserLocation doesnt get called everytime.

What I want to do is smoothly changing position with these methods faster and animating the circle like user location (blue dot) changes (dispatch wont do any of this tasks faster)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self UpdateCirclePosition];
}
```

This method get executed when user location changes.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation1
{
    [self UpdateCirclePosition];
}
```

This method is to set new coordinates for the circle

```
-(void)UpdateCirclePosition
{
    //Removing past layouts from MapView
    [self.mapView removeOverlays: [self.mapView overlays]];

    //Set the circle in the middle of the current user location
    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:locationManager.location.coordinate radius:10];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:circle];
}
```

And this is the method when overlay changes

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    if (something)
    {
        circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
    }
    else
    {
        circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
    }
    circleView.lineWidth = 0.5;
    return circleView;
}
```

Comment: Note that didUpdateUserLocation is an _MKMapView_ delegate method and in UpdateCirclePosition, it looks like you're using the current location from a _CLLocationManager_.  It's possible they are not exactly in sync.  Use _either_ the user location you get from the MKMapView (as Craig suggests) or call UpdateCirclePosition from the  _CLLocationManager_ delegate method didUpdateLocations.

Comment: Thnx Anna, your answers are always so helpful. I wanted to contact you and ask you about suggestions you can give me, since I am a new iOS developer! Anyway thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didUpdateUserLocation` gets the latest position, but then you ignore it and call `UpdateCirclePosition`. You should pass the coordinates from `userLocation1` into `UpdateCirclePosition` and use them to reposition your circle.

Comment: Thanks Craig, this is something I have missed! I wanna ask another question but its outside of the topic, the only way to move position of the circle is by remove and readding it again?

Comment: MKOverlay protocol conforms MKAnnotation which should have a setCoordinate function. THough I haven't tried it I imagine implementing that should do it. If not you'll need to ask a new question to get attention from someone who knows.